# can't rotate a circle node around a fix point

Tags: sprite-kit, rotation, gestures, skshapenode

I'm trying to set a `SKShapeNode` that rotating around fixed point depend on user's swipe gesture. to do so i'm using the code that answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143382/drag-rotate-a-node-around-a-fixed-point)

when I set the node as a rectangle - it's working just fine, the problem is when I trying to set the node as a circle (as I needed it to be). I have no idea why its happening, and what makes the difference.

here is the code that works (`SKShapeNode` as a rectangle):

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let ball = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.red
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    ball.name = "BALL"
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 200)
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.25
    ball.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(ball)

    let om = 5.0
    let er = 4.0
    let omer = atan2(om, er)
    print("om = \(om), er = \(er), atan2(omer) = \(omer)")


}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "BALL" {
            let dx = location.x - node.position.x
            let dy = location.y - node.position.y
            // Store angle and current time
            startingAngle = atan2(dy, dx)
            startingTime = touch.timestamp
            node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.location(in:self)
        let node = atPoint(location)
        if node.name == "BALL" {
            let dx = location.x - node.position.x
            let dy = location.y - node.position.y

            let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
            // Calculate angular velocity; handle wrap at pi/-pi
            var deltaAngle = angle - startingAngle!
            if abs(deltaAngle) > CGFloat.pi {
                if (deltaAngle > 0) {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle - CGFloat.pi * 2
                }
                else {
                    deltaAngle = deltaAngle + CGFloat.pi * 2
                }
            }
            let dt = CGFloat(touch.timestamp - startingTime!)
            let velocity = deltaAngle / dt

            node.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = velocity

            // Update angle and time
            startingAngle = angle
            startingTime = touch.timestamp
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startingAngle = nil
    startingTime = nil
}
```

but when i change the `SKShapeNode` (inside my `didMove` function) to circle is just dont work - here is the changed code:

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 200)
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.red
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    ball.name = "BALL"
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 200)
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0.25
    ball.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.addChild(ball)

}
```

does anyone see/ know what am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How would you expect to see that the shape is turning? Do you have something inside the shapenode with a texture that you can actually see rotating?

A turning circle shapenode looks the same as a static one. In the update loop of the scene grab the ball and print its zRotation to see if it's actually turning.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    var ball: SKShapeNode = childNodeWithName("BALL") as SKShapeNode
    print(ball.zRotation)
}
```

**(this code was written without access to Swift so you might have to fix the syntax a tiny bit)**

**Remember the zRotation is measured in radians** so it might not look how you expect but it it's changing then the SKShapeNode is actually rotating, you just can't see it. 
You'll have to add a child node that has something visible on it.