# Spin node on fixed point - SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I’m trying to make a “spin the wheel” using SceneKit. The user drags the wheel around on a fixed point and the the wheel will maintain some momentum after the user let’s go while still slowing down.

I’ve found how to do this using SpriteKit but I’m not sure how to do it using SceneKit. [Drag Rotate a Node around a fixed point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143382/drag-rotate-a-node-around-a-fixed-point)

Comment: Which do you need to know? Input handling or spinning and damping angular momentum in SceneKit?

Comment: Mainly input handling as I could try use the rest if the stuff from the answer linked above. But if I could get all of it together (I’m still a kinda new to coding) it’d be really helpful. @Confused